# Проблема в работе мышки

Tags: мышь, электроника

Есть мышка A4tech bloody v8, появилась следующая проблема: произвольно может сработать вместо левого клика - правый, особенно часто на рабочем столе. В браузере же бывает не срабатывает правый клик с 1ого нажатия, а вместо этого требуется 4-5 нажатий. Проблема появляется где-то после 20-30 минут использования мышки. Но так же может появится этот "баг" и через какое-то время пропасть. Мышку разобрал, почистил, микровыключатели внешне нормальные, платы и шлейфы тоже. Через официальное ПО от bloody ребутал мышку - не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: плата]
[image: верх]

Comment: У микропереключателей как правило ограниченное число нажатий. Я бы копал в эту сторону: ставишь мультиметр на "прозвонку" и щёлкаешь микрики.

Comment: @0andriy проблема была в кварцевом резонаторе.